# How add Delphi XE2 64bit support to a simple Delphi XE2 32bit VCL component?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe2, vcl

I need convert a VCL component from 32bit to 64bit (Delphi XE2). Now infact I can install it only if I select "32bit Platform", if I select "64bit Platform" I can compile it but not install (there is not the install menu).
How can I add 64bit support and install it for 64bit application?

Comment: You can install a 64-bit application only on a 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 20):

If you mean "install it into the IDE", the simple answer is that you cannot.

The IDE is a 32-bit application and is not designed to host 64-bit DLL's.  Any components or plug-ins must be compiled for 32-bit in order to work with the IDE itself.

64-bit support in a component is for runtime support only, not design-time.

Comment: +1 I'd not even considered this particular nuance with respect to packages. I guess it's pretty unlikely that you'd ever feel the need to run the design time code under 64 bit.

Comment: You would not be able to, since the IDE itself is 32-bit, so it cannot run 64-bit code at all.  Debugging 64-bit runtime code, on the other hand, is done by running the remote debugger on a 64-bit machine and connecting to it with the IDE.

Comment: In summary: to add a 64 bit to a simple VCL I can add 64 bit platform on package;
In any case I must only install it as 32 bit because the IDE is 32 bit application, then I will see the VCL on palette with support both for 32 and 64 bit.
This is ok, I just have test it for some VCL and works.
However I have a VCL with some problem, after add the 64 bit platform and installed it without problem I see that it can works only on 32 bit (from palette).
Is there a way to understand why this component cannot works on 64 bit? To find if there is a wrong code...