# Firemonkey designide.dcp 64 bit

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe4, firemonkey-fm3

Has anyone successfully build a custom component in Firemonkey using designide.dcp for a 64 bit OS?
I am trying to add a design editor to a custom component.  I followed the tutorial on http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Creating_a_Component_Editor_and_a_Property_Editor_for_FireMonkey_Components.
This works just fine when compiling to 32 bit, but I get the following error for 64 bit : 
[dcc64 Fatal Error] ComponentEditor.pas(10): E2213 Bad packaged unit format: c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\11.0\lib\win32\release\designide.dcp.DesignEditors - Expected version: 25.0, Windows Unicode(x64) Found version: 25.0, Windows Unicode(x86)

Looking at the path this makes sense as the file refer to lib\win32.  However, under lib\win64 there is no such file.

I've been trying to find a solution on the internet without any luck.  It does not look like many people have tried this yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How add Delphi XE2 64bit support to a simple Delphi XE2 32bit VCL component?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719297/how-add-delphi-xe2-64bit-support-to-a-simple-delphi-xe2-32bit-vcl-component) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972060/delphi-xe2-package-x64 o

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no `designide.dcp` for 64 bit. The IDE (and therefore all of the design time code) is 32-bit. It can compile 64-bit targets, but the IDE itself (and any components and packages) are 32-bit only.

Comment: Thank you.  That make sense.  I did not thought about that.